# Put data in class declaration?

Tags: c++, object, declaration

In [one of Stroustrup's faq question](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#data-in-class), he gives following example:

```
template<class Scalar> class complex {
public:
    complex() : re(0), im(0) { }
    complex(Scalar r) : re(r), im(0) { }
    complex(Scalar r, Scalar i) : re(r), im(i) { }
    // ...

    complex& operator+=(const complex& a)
        { re+=a.re; im+=a.im; return *this; }
    // ...
private:
    Scalar re, im;
};
```

and describes:

This type is designed to be used much as a built-in type and **the representation is needed in the declaration to make it possible to create genuinely local objects** (i.e. objects that are allocated on the stack and not on a heap) **and to ensure proper inlining of simple operations**.

Would someone explain this? Put `re`, `im` data in class declaration makes class object allocate on stack? And what about inlining? (I can see a `operator+=` inlined, does he mean this?)

Comment: I've removed the second question. Feel free to ask that again, but if you do, provide the source code you're wondering about.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are referring to ``complex`` as a "base class"? It makes the question title misleading.

Comment: Thanks juanchopanza. Corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the data in the class definition doesn't make the object
allocate on stack, but it allows it.  At the point where the object is
defined, the compiler must know its complete size; if the object is to
be defined on the stack, the compiler must know its size in the
translation unit which defines it.

Not putting the data in the class definition means that you must take
some steps to allocate the data elsewhere, and that elsewhere will
almost certainly involve dynamic allocation.

Similarly, an inline function can only manipulate data that it sees.

There are various schemas for avoiding data declarations in the class.
They can have important advantages, especially when the data types are
complex and user defined.  They all do involve dynamic allocation.  What
Stroustrup is saying that for small, concrete classes, putting the data
in the class allows them to behave (and perform) like the built-in
types, with no dynamic allocation, and often (because of inlining) no
abstraction penalty.

Comment: Thanks James. Well written and make sense.

Answer (score 3):

This is a concrete class that is not intended to be derived from (because there is no need).

You probably don't want to define an interface for complex numbers, and derive different kinds of complex numbers (whatever that would be) and use them polymorphically.

By having everything in the class, the compiler can probably easier optimize this than when using an abstract interface and virtual functions.

I don't think there is anything magic here, it is just an example of where using a "value type" class is appropriate.

Comment: Thanks Bo. When i read some of Stroustrup's faq, i sometimes got confused in the way he explains. Often try to be certain that i actually don't miss major points.

Answer (score 3):

The members `re` and `im` are allocated inside every `complex` object. That means that `re` and `im` are allocated on the stack *if and only if* the whole `complex` object is. If the `complex` object is a global, then `re` and `im` are neither on the stack nor on the heap.

In practice, compilers will put `re` at offset 0 in the object and `im` at offset `sizeof(Scalar)`. This means that the code for `operator+=` doesn't take a lot of assembly instruction to fetch those members. The actual additions themselves probably are just two assembly instruction, so loading the 4 members and storing the two results is a major fraction of the work. And inlining works best if there's little to inline.